# Results not showing after converting PDO query to mySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have a script to extract data from two tables `matieres` and `sous_matieres` but it's written for **PDO**, I need it to work for **mySQLi**:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT 
                        m.id AS m_id, m.url AS m_url, m.title AS m_title, 
                        s.id AS s_id, s.url AS s_url, s.title AS s_title
                     FROM matieres m
                     INNER JOIN sous_matieres s ON m.url = s.parent');

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['url'] = $row->m_url;
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['title'] = $row->m_title;
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['sous_matieres'][$row->s_id] = $row;
}

foreach ($matieres as $m_id => $matiere) {
    echo "<h2>$matiere[title]</h2>";
    foreach ($matiere['sous_matieres'] as $id => $sm) {
        echo "<div>
                  <a href='{$sm->s_url}'>{$sm->s_title}</a>
              </div>";
    }
}
```

My new **mySQLi** code that shows nothing despite the two tables have data:

```
$query = 'SELECT 
              m.id AS m_id, m.url AS m_url, m.title AS m_title, 
              s.id AS s_id, s.url AS s_url, s.title AS s_title
          FROM matieres m
          INNER JOIN sous_matieres s ON m.url = s.parent';
$stmt = $mysqli->query($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['url'] = $row->m_url;
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['title'] = $row->m_title;
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['sous_matieres'][$row->s_id] = $row;
}

foreach ($matieres as $m_id => $matiere) {
    echo "<h2>$matiere[title]</h2>";
    foreach ($matiere['sous_matieres'] as $id => $sm) {
        echo "<div>
                  <a href='{$sm->s_url}'>{$sm->s_title}</a>
              </div>";
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's missing `$stmt->bind_result()` and the variable inside. As for normal mySQLi queries (without joins) I have to declare the selected column names as variable inside the `$stmt->bind_result()`

Comment: I think `$mysqli->query()` already returns the executed statement (unless weird wrapper). Calling `->execute()` may do things you don't intend... als ... if you execute ... actually catch the return value for debugging purposes. (anyway, I'm uncertain, why you would switch to mysqli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt::fetch` is used when you bind variables to results on a prepared statement, to populate those variables. The alternative method of getting the results is to use the `mysqli_result` class, which you can use the way you're trying to:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['url'] = $row->m_url;
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['title'] = $row->m_title;
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['sous_matieres'][$row->s_id] = $row;
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php.

Comment: Sorry but is $result->fetchObject() a valid mySQLi function? I thought it's PDO only and it's the equivalent of $result->fetch() for mySQLi

Comment: For such questions it's best to refer to the manual, which can answer them clearly and directly. I've linked to the relevant page for you above.

Comment: When displaying errors: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchObject()

Comment: Are you sure you're using the return value `$mysqli->query()`...?

Comment: Ah, darn typo. See, that's why you're supposed to RTFM! ;-P